# Comparing transaction counts between samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, count-data, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a treatment group and two control groups for customers and the count of their transactions:

```
Treatment Group
Customer | Transaction Count
-----------------------------
1        | 0
2        | 2
3        | 3
4        | 0 ...

Control Group 1
Customer | Transaction Count
-----------------------------
1        | 1
2        | 2
3        | 0
4        | 3 ...
```

Each group has approximately 50 customers, ranging from 0-20 transactions, with low numbers (0-5) being most common.

I want to test the hypothesis that customers in the treatment group have the same number of transactions when compared to customers in either control group.

I keep coming back to the Kruskal-Wallis test, since the counts are definitely not distributed normally. However, I'm a bit worried since there would be a high number of ties (for example, lots of zeros), and my understanding is that the rankings should be clearly ordered.

Is there a more appropriate hypothesis test for this question, or should I stick with the Kruskal-Wallis test?